# declare global namespace variable from TypeScript

Tags: meteor, typescript

How to explicitly declare a variable in the global namespace from typescript?

I need the compiler to generate the following javascript code:

```
MyExtension = someFunction()
```

unfortunately, I can only have it generate

```
var MyExtension = someFunction()
```

This comes to an issue with the latest version (still in rc) of meteor packages.
   Meteor introduced a way to scope namespaces in packages - the issue is,  the variable needs to be defined in the global namespace (which meteor reroutes to its own Package object).

There is a video about it at https://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-linker-package-namespacing.

Is there some kind of `global` keyword available or in the plans?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use the `declare` keyword. These are known as ambient declarations.

```
declare var MyExtentention:any;
```

Comment: In my experience, this has to go at the top of the file. If you place this inside another variable declaration, e.g., near where you are using the global variable, the compiler will complain that "Modifiers cannot appear here".