# Environment variables in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, environment-variables

If we have some environment variables which are present in the environment in  which the compiled JavaScript is going to run, how we can mention those variables in Typescript code ?

In TypeScript varaibles cannot be used without being declared. If it is declared like `let env_varaible;`, it become `var env_variable;` which eventually overridethe actual varaible. What is the solution for this?

Comment: So why you can use just `env.variable`?

Comment: during compilation typescript will show  - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'env_variable'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell TypeScript about a variable created by globals (coming directly from JavaScript runtime environment or any external source) with:

```
declare var env_variable;
```

Typescript won't throw an error for undeclared `env_variable` variable.

See also: [declare global namespace variable from TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171967/declare-global-namespace-variable-from-typescript)